# Can we write multiple SQL Queries in Power BI to load it to Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, azure-synapse

Can we write a series of SQL statements like Insert, Update, Delete, Create Table from Power BI to Azure Synapse instead of using sql server management studio.

I am aware that we can do while logging into powerbi desktop. Is there a way where we can do this after login.

Comment: You can use the Synapse web portal to write the starments as well as Data Studio which is better just for writing stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Power BI has a query editor to sort out what you want to see from your data source. The reason is because PBI can connect to tons of different data sources which require their own unique commands. For example, the SQL code for an Azure DB is a bit different than the SQL commands needed on a MySQL database. So they standardized it. Here's [a bit more reading the MS PBI forum.](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/New-to-BI-Writing-SQL-queries-to-parse-data-I-am-obviously/td-p/41415)